# $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ are any three vectors mutually perpendicular to each other.

Tags: vectors

Let $\vec{p}$ and $\vec{q}$ be any two orthogonal vectors of equal magnitude 4 each.Let $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ are any three vectors of lengths $7,\sqrt{15}$ and $2\sqrt{33}$,mutually perpendicular to each other.Then find the distance of the vector
$(\vec{a}.\vec{p})\vec{p}+(\vec{a}.\vec{q})\vec{q}+(\vec{a}.(\vec{p}\times\vec{q}))(\vec{p}\times\vec{q})+
(\vec{b}.\vec{p})\vec{p}+(\vec{b}.\vec{q})\vec{q}+(\vec{b}.(\vec{p}\times\vec{q}))(\vec{p}\times\vec{q})
+(\vec{c}.\vec{p})\vec{p}+(\vec{c}.\vec{q})\vec{q}+(\vec{c}.(\vec{p}\times\vec{q}))(\vec{p}\times\vec{q})$ from the origin.

---

I tried to attempt this question.But i could not do much.Please help me in solving this.I will appreciate any help.Thanks.

Comment: Proving one proves the others by symmetry. However I am not sure it works unless $|\vec p| = | \vec q| = 1$, as I can scale those vectors, and the third term destroys homogeneity.  i.e. if the equations hold for some vectors, just scale $\vec p, \vec q$ by a factor of $2$, and you will find the third term will cause the equations to fail.

Comment: @Macavity,i have written the original book question above.Is it still not valid?

Comment: Now that is a **very** different question from the one you asked originally. The issue of scaling vanishes, because you are now looking only at a particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$\vec{r}=(\vec{a}.\vec{p})\vec{p}+(\vec{a}.\vec{q})\vec{q}+(\vec{a}.(\vec{p}\times\vec{q}))(\vec{p}\times\vec{q})$$

Taking dot product with $\vec{p}$ and $\vec{q}$ on both sides we get

$$\vec{r}.\vec{p}=(\vec{a}.\vec{p})|\vec{p}|^2 \tag{1}$$ and

$$\vec{r}.\vec{q}=(\vec{a}.\vec{q})|\vec{q}|^2 \tag{2}$$ Subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$ we get

$$\vec{r}.(\vec{p}-\vec{q})=|\vec{p}|^2\vec{a}.(\vec{p}-\vec{q})$$ $\implies$

$$(\vec{r}-\vec{a}|\vec{p}|^2).(\vec{p}-\vec{q})=0$$

which is possible only if $$\vec{r}=\vec{a}|\vec{p}|^2$$ OR $\vec{p}-\vec{q}$ is orthogonal to $\vec{r}-\vec{a}|\vec{p}|^2$. I am not sure how to rule out second condition.

Answer (score 0):

This question has no answer(Or this is an invalid question).

Let $$
\vec{a}=x_1\vec{p}+x_2\vec{q}+x_3\vec{p}\times \vec{q},
$$
$$
\vec{b}=y_1\vec{p}+y_2\vec{q}+y_3\vec{p}\times \vec{q},
$$
$$
\vec{c}=z_1\vec{p}+z_2\vec{q}+z_3\vec{p}\times \vec{q},
$$
Then $$
\vec{a}^2=16x_1^2+16x_2^2+16^2x_3^2=49,
$$
$$
\vec{b}^2=16y_1^2+16y_2^2+16^2y_3^2=15,
$$
$$
\vec{c}^2=16z_1^2+16z_2^2+16^2z_3^2=132.
$$
Then $$
\begin{align*}
&(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{p}) \vec{p}+(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{q}) \vec{q}+(\vec{a} \cdot(\vec{p} \times \vec{q}))(\vec{p} \times \vec{q})+(\vec{b} \cdot \vec{p}) \vec{p}+(\vec{b} \cdot \vec{q}) \vec{q}+(\vec{b} \cdot(\vec{p} \times \vec{q}))(\vec{p} \times \vec{q})+(\vec{c} \cdot \vec{p}) \vec{p}+(\vec{c} \cdot \vec{q}) \vec{q}+(\vec{c} \cdot(\vec{p} \times \vec{q}))(\vec{p} \times \vec{q})
\\&=x_1\vec{p}^2 \vec{p}+x_2\vec{q}^2\vec{q}+x_3(\vec{p}\times \vec{q})^2 (\vec{p}\times \vec{q})+y_1\vec{p}^2 \vec{p}+y_2\vec{q}^2\vec{q}+y_3(\vec{p}\times \vec{q})^2 (\vec{p}\times \vec{q})+z_1\vec{p}^2 \vec{p}+z_2\vec{q}^2\vec{q}+z_3(\vec{p}\times \vec{q})^2 (\vec{p}\times \vec{q})
\\&=16x_1\vec{p}+16x_2\vec{q}+16^2x_3 \vec{p}\times \vec{q}+16y_1\vec{p}+16y_2\vec{q}+16^2y_3 \vec{p}\times \vec{q}+16z_1\vec{p}+16z_2\vec{q}+16^2z_3 \vec{p}\times \vec{q}.
\end{align*}
$$
So the distance of the vector from the origin is $$
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{16^3(x_1^2+x_2^2+y_1^2+y_2^2+z_1^2+z_2^2)+16^6(x_3^2+y_3^2+z_3^2)}&=4^3 \sqrt{(x_1^2+x_2^2+y_1^2+y_2^2+z_1^2+z_2^2)+4^6(x_3^2+y_3^2+z_3^2)}
\\&=\sqrt{16711680(x_3^2+y_3^2+z_3^2)+50176}
\end{align*}
$$
But $x_3^2+y_3^2+z_3^2$ can not be determined in nature.